# asp.net-App_global.asax could not be loaded

Tags: c#, asp.net, visual-studio-2010, runtime-error

I have started a new project in Visual Studio 2010. I went to New->Project->ASP.Net Web Application. As expected, the Application opened with default.aspx and about.aspx

When I build the solution(*not a single word of code has been entered*) I get the following error on my browser:

[image: Error Image]

I looked up `C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Temp\Temporary ASP.NET Files\root\ee0be88c\bfc80d79` and found that the specified dll was not getting created. Here is my folder:

[image: foo]

What is the problem? How do I fix this?
**Edit:**I am already running VS2010 as administrator.

Comment: delete obj folder from project and try again

Comment: Was there ever a fix for this? im having the exact same issue and ive tried all the answers below.

Answer (score 0):

you need to make sure that the user your application is running under, has atleast modify access to the temporary asp.net foler

Comment: I am running the application as administrator.

Comment: is your application using impersonation? if not, then make sure the aspnet user has modift access.

Comment: Nope. no impersonation.

Answer (score 0):

when you want start visual studio, instead of double click to run, right click on it and Run it as Administrator.

Comment: did you clean and rebuild after that?

Comment: yes. The build was successful. But the error is the same. I don't know why but the dll files are _not_ getting created.

Answer (score 0):

You need to run Visual Studio on Administrator. Just right click on the visual studio icon and clik on **Run as Administrator**